# Recommended way to organize and build multiple services for App Engine Flexible Environment with custom runtime

Tags: python, google-app-engine, docker

When deploying to Flexible Environment using the default runtime (e.g. `python`), we just need to specify different `app.yaml` files with different `entrypoint:` values.

But what would the 'best practice' for custom runtimes be for this case?

Multiple `Dockerfile`'s with different `CMD` values?

But that would mean that each service needs to be built individually. Maybe have a 'base' Dockerfile and image to speed up the build?

Answer (score 1):

Copying my answer to a question on Stack Overflow
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49388615/multiple-services-with-different-dockerfiles-on-gae-flexible/58119935#58119935

tl;dr: build a separate docker image, push it to GCR, deploy using that image.

Specify a custom runtime. 
Build the image locally, tag it, and push it to Google Container Registry (GCR)
then, deploy your service, specifying a custom service file, and specifying the remote image on GCR using the --image-url option.

Here's an example that accomplishes different entrypoints in 2 services that share the same code:
...this is assuming that the "flex" and not "standard" app engine offering is being used.

lets say you have a project called *my-proj*
with  a default service that is not important
and a second service called *queue-processor* which is using much of the same code from the same directory.
Create a separate dockerfile for it called *QueueProcessorDockerfile* 
and a separate app.yaml called *queue-processor-app.yaml* to tell google app engine what i want to happen.

`QueueProcessorDockerfile`

```
FROM node:10
# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json ./
COPY yarn.lock ./
RUN npm install -g yarn
RUN yarn
# Bundle app source
COPY . .
CMD [ "yarn", "process-queue" ]
```

*of course i have a "process-queue" script in my package.json
`queue-processor-app.yaml`

```
runtime: custom
env: flex
... other stuff...
...
```

1. build and tag the docker image
   Check out googles guide here -> https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/pushing-and-pulling
   docker build -t eu.gcr.io/my-proj/queue-processor -f QueueProcessorDockerfile .
2. push it to GCR
   docker push eu.gcr.io/my-proj/queue-processor
3. deploy the service, specifying which yaml config file google should use, as well as the image url you have pushed
   gcloud app deploy queue-processor-app.yaml --image-url eu.gcr.io/my-proj/queue-processor

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of using a default flexible runtime or a custom one you *always* need an `app.yaml` for every service in your app. The difference is in *the content* of the `app.yaml` file (apart from the Dockerfile needed for custom runtimes). From  [Building Custom Runtimes](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/build):

> To create a custom runtime you need:
>
> - An app.yaml file that describes your application's runtime configuration.
> - A Dockerfile that configures the runtime environment. In many cases, this can be just one line specifying a base image.

...

> Create an app.yaml file
>
> You must use an `app.yaml` configuration file with the following
>   settings:
>
> ```
> runtime: custom
> env: flex
> ```

...

> Create a Dockerfile
>
> The Dockerfile is always named `Dockerfile` and should be placed in
>   the same directory with the corresponding `app.yaml` file.

The actual content of a service's dockerfile depends on what the service is supposed to do. Theoretically the Dockerfiles contents could even be identical - there is no risk of collisions since they *must* be located in different directories (since their name is fixed). This is in line with the recommended dir structure of a multi-service/module app (the image is now gone, but it was captured in [this older SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34110178/can-a-default-module-in-a-google-app-engine-app-be-a-sibling-of-a-non-default-mo))